# XML parsing with application loading

Tags: android, xml, optimization

I write simple project in android. I have ~10 activities, and the user flipping them. In main activity I must parse very big XML file and load this information into some array. But if the user turns the main activity off and goes back to it, my main activity parses big XML file again. Can I parse it once and save in the memory while the user turns the activities?

Comment: you can make the parse done in a thread within a class which an application class.Form more information about application class :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: are you parsing the xml inside of onCreate()?

Comment: Tim, I use "startParsing();" inside onCreate()
Zied, thanks, I will see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Singleton that parse the XML in the constructor, and use get to get the data.

Comment: But why parsing every time? It is battery consuming. If you think it can make your program ANR so make a thread in the singleton. But DO NOT parse twice.